# How to set up Laravel 5 for OS X server?

Tags: php, macos, laravel, server

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up my OS X Server to run Laravel. I noticed a few things..

1. I needed to update my php, so I used the method described here and updated to 7.0
   http://php-osx.liip.ch
2. OpenSSL was not installed, so I used the following guide to install it,
   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x

Now I'm unable to load a simple php file that spits out the PHP version. I'm not sure what went wrong.

When I try to load the php file that echo's out the version I get a blank white screen. I'm using a valid SSL certificate as well.

Any thing else I need to do? Anyone know why I can't load anything now?

Thanks!

Comment: I would check Laravel error log (in `storage/logs`) and the error log of whatever web server software you use (Apache, nginx, etc.).

Comment: Step 1: Delete OSX server
Step 2: Do not use OSX server

Comment: Server has it's own apache configuration. Laravel needs a newer version of PHP than what is shipped with OS X server. I had to go into the OS X Server httpd.conf and comment out PHP 5, and add a line for PHP 7. Everything worked after that. (OS X server seems to always override your changes in the configuration file, so if things break, go check the config again.)